# share a byte[] file via bluetooth

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, share, manifest

i want to share a file which is byte[] via bluetooth.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
            intent.setType("text/byte");//what type ?


            String uri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Keys/"+"public.key";
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(uri)));
            startActivity(intent);
```

what type should I call ???

and also do I need to change manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe manifest file is missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```